# Adding additional characters into the String Formatting key field

Tags: python, string-formatting

I am trying to create a basic key/value table that looks like below:

```
someKey:               some info
aReallyLongKey:        more info
somthingElse:          other info
```

Without the colons, this is really easy:

```
formatter = "{key:<25}{value}"

for k,v in myDict.items():
    print(formatter.format(key=k, value=v))
```

However, this will not include the ":" after the key. What I want is something like this (this doesn't work):

`formatter = "{key+':':<25}{value}"`

Essentially, I want to append something to the key so that I get:
`formatter.format(key=k+":", value=v)`, but with the appended ":" in the `formatter` string.

I've tried doing some nesting, but couldn't get that to work. Is there an elegant, native, Pythonic way to append the ":" to the key in the string formatter so that I can still use the `<25` formatting over the entire "key:" part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using python 3.6+ you can do this easily using `f-strings`:

```
for k,v in myDict.items():
    print(f"{f'{k}:':<25}{v}")
    #or
    print(f"{k + ':':<25}{v}")
```

Otherwise just append the colon before it's formatted (just like you were asking):

```
formatter = "{key:<25}{value}".format
for k,v in myDict.items():
    print(formatter(key=k+':', value=v))
```